# "Does someone of you know" vs "Does some of you know"

Tags: pronouns

When I want to ask my friends if they know the full name of one of our teachers, then what is the correct way to do so?

> a) "Does **someone** of you know the full name of our chemistry
>   teacher"
>
> b) "Does **some** of you know the full name of our chemistry teacher"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use **someone** in affirmative clauses and **anyone** in negative and interrogative clauses. This is a question, so you should use **anyone**. See [this link](https://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/somebody-someone-anybody-anyone-etc/) for more information.

When you ask this question, you are expecting each person to consider their own situation, rather than have somebody answering on behalf of the whole group. So, rather than saying "Does some of you..", you ask "Does anyone...".

> Does anyone know the full name of our chemistry teacher?

Note that **some** is plural, so your question b should have been "Do some of you.."

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I appreciate it but I'm confused because you apparently said two different things. In the beginning you've said that I should use **anybody** but in the end you've said that I should use **anyone**.

Comment: @AdorableSpectacle My mistake. **anyone** and **anybody** are identical in meaning. I have updated the answer to make it consistent.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be "Does anyone know the full name of our chemistry teacher?"

Another option might be "Do any of you know the full name of our chemistry teacher?" 
But that is more appropriate if you are face-to-face with a group of people. If you are on the internet, I'd use "Does anyone know the full name of our chemistry teacher?"